# How can I test for long configuration changes in Android?

Tags: android, service

I've had a problem with my app where there were crashes due to configuration changes.

Basically some `AsyncTask`s where returning a result, having started before a configuration change and finishing after one.

To solve this I made up a scheme where each `Activity` would register itself as a receiver of results in `Application` upon loading , unregister itself upon being destroyed and all the background work would run on an `IntentService` by the `Application` class which is currently responsible for sending the message to the `IntentService` retrieving the result, and either sending it to the appropriate receiver, holding it for a set time until a valid receiver is registered, or dismissing the result.

This seems to work under normal circumstances, and solves my problems with the receiver being a different instance of the `Activity` that requested the action, but I can't test the situation where the configuration takes too long to complete (something along the lines of the screen taking too long to switch from portrait to landscape) so the `Application` has to save the result for the (not created yet) receiver.

Is there a way to trigger this type of event?

Also if someone else has a better solution to my problem (other than Loaders) I would be grateful for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate that by registering your `Activity` after a certain time delay.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Register Activity here
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: doh, I feel stupid, I use postdelayed to clean up the undelivered results but it didn't occur to me to do it for testing, thanks a lot for the help